# Search.php not working showing blank page when item is found

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have no experience in coding... please help!!!
Search bar is not giving results just blank page! can you please help me solve this issue!
When the search query is wrong the "not found" message appears as expected but no results when they should appear.. 
Please tell me if I need to share a specific code

Search.php

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'Searching';
require_once('includes/wrapper/header.php');

$string = '';

if($_POST['string'] != '') {
$string = htmlentities($_POST['string']);

} else {

header('Location: index.php');

}

$emoji = New Read();


 ?>
<div class="hero">
         <div>
            <h2><?php echo $string; ?> Emoji</h2>
            <p>
               You are currently searching for <?php echo $string; ?> emoji
            </p>
         </div>


<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="search.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="search" placeholder="Search Emoji... eg: Heart" name="string">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn searchbtn btn-lg btn-default btn-red">Search Emoji</button>
</form>
<div class="banner-ad">
<?php 
require_once('includes/wrapper/banner_ad.php');
 ?>
</div>

      </div>



<section id="#people">
<div class="container">

<div class="emoji-content">
<?php 

$items = $emoji->search_emoji($string);
if(!empty($items)) {
foreach($items as $item) {
echo '<a class="copy" data-clipboard-text="&#x' . $item['unicode'] . '"><span class="emoji"><img src="assets/img/emoji/' . $item['unicode'] . '.png" width="70px" alt="' . $item['name'] . '"></span></a>';

} } else {

echo '<center><h2>No emoji matched your search terms....</center></h2>';

}?>
</div>
</div>







<?php require_once('includes/wrapper/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: By "blank page" do you mean completly blank?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? If you're unsure how to check for errors, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: Not  completely blank, just the results do not show!

Comment: Likely an error which isnt coming through. Your PHP upgrade fixes it, but it might be valueble to know *why* that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED THE PROBLEM. BY CHANGING PHP VERSION TO 7.0

Comment: Hi. If the question isnt really usable by anyone else because of a specific issue on your side (like this is), it's recommended to delete your answer/topic so that it doesnt 'polute'  :)

Comment: Also, 7.0 is OLD, you should go for 7.2 or higher :)